# How to assign a task name from Classic designer in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I'm using Classic pipeline in the Azure Pipelines, I can only set `displayName` for a task/step. I can't set a `name` for a task/step. But in YAML, I can assign a `name` for a task/step.

I'd like to know that, is it possible to set a `name` for a task/step? Or is there a **Default name** for each task?

In [Set variable properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-4015686#set-variable-properties), I don't know how to get `name` of a task when I'm using classic designer in Azure Pipelines.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: @KevinLu-MSFT Thank you. I need find some time to test your suggestion. Just wait a moment.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to let me know if you have any further questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the Classic Pipeline, you can set the name for the task/step via the **Output Variables -> Reference name** Option.

[image]

This option will add the prefix name of the **Output** variable. You need to add the **isoutput=true** when you defining the variable.

For example:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myvalue;isoutput=true]myvalue"
```

In the next tasks, you can use the variable with the format: `$(taskname.myvalue)`.

In this case, the task name in Classic Pipeline will have the same feature of Yaml Pipeline.

> is there a Default name for each task?

Yes. If you don't set the task name, it will add the default prefix name to the Output variable.

For example:

```
- Powershell: set variable1
- PowerShell: set variable2
```

Then the output variable will use the default prefix: `$(powershell1.variable1)` and `$(powershell2.variable2)`

Answer (score 0):

When creating a build step you decide on the steps name, as defined in the task.json of each step, for example:

```
{
  "id": "5cbab033-****-****-****-9c2541bac3e4",
  "name": "**TestStep**",
  "friendlyName": "**TEST: Testing**",
  "description": "This is a test"
.
.
.
}
```

In this example, the official name of the build step is: TestStep, although the name that would appear is the friendly name: TEST: Testing

You can go ahead and update the friendly name to whatever you want, or if you want to update the defined name you have the following options:

1. To change this per pipeline you can go ahead and update in the
   "Output Variable" -> Reference name and give new prefix to the name.
2. To literally override the name of the step you can
   reupload the build step using tfx.